# Android format data

Tags: android

I have a textView in the layout. The data I am displaying is a huge text with "tabs" in them. I would like to diaplay it in readable format. How do I format that in android ? Is that a right direction or it can be formatted using something else...

Comment: You mean, remove tab spaces? You may use string.replaceAll("\t", " ");

Comment: I am trying to replace "*" with that replaceAll. Not working. what else can I do....

Comment: String temp = "Hello*Hello*TEST*HELLO";
             temp =temp.replaceAll("\\*", " ");
             System.out.println("Temp is: "+temp);   It is working for me.

Comment: Doesn't work in java. It's saying Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are  \b  \t  \n  \f  \r  \"  \'  \\ )

Comment: ahhh! I see what was the mistake. inside replaceAll(twoslashes*, " "), somehow comment removed another slash. Try with two slashes. Add another slash

Comment: Glad it worked. I have added it as answer. Please accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example on how to do:

```
String temp = "Hello*Hello*TEST*HELLO"; 
temp =temp.replaceAll("\\*", " "); 
System.out.println("Temp is: "+temp);
```